# How to cache queries using Nuxt.js Apollo client?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

My query `fetchPolicy` is set to `cache-first`. But Apollo doesn't cache the queries. For example, when I switch off my gql server, It returns NetworkError on client server.
Where can I see if the query is cached or not? I have Apollo dev tool Chrome extension and I can see there that my query is cached!

[image]

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
export default {
   modules: ['@nuxtjs/apollo'],
   apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: '~/apollo.js',
    },
  },
}
```

**apollo.js**

```js
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

export default (context) => {
  return {
    httpEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  }
}
```

**pages/index.vue**

```html
<script>
import getProducts from '~/queries/getProducts.gql'
export default {
  async asyncData({ app }) {
    let client = app.apolloProvider.defaultClient
    const products = await client.query({
      query: getProducts,
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
    })
    return { products }
  },
}
</script>
```

It doesn't matter if the query is on server side or client side, both of them doesn't cache the queries:

```js
  mounted() {
    this.$apollo
      .query({
        query: getProducts,
        prefetch: false,
        fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
      })
      .then((data) => (this.products = data))
  },
```

I also tried the Apollo specified method but was the same issue:

```js
  apollo: {
    products: {
      query: getProducts,
      prefetch: true,
      fetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
    },
  },
```

When I use `cache-only`, the `products` are empty and nothing to show.

What's the problem?

Comment: Do you have the issue if you reach the page with the `cache-first` policy on a server-side navigation only or both server + client navigation?

Comment: @kissu On both sides have this issue, question updated.

Comment: @kissu Here is codesandbox example that u can see the cache could not be saved: https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-js-apollo-cache-e30it